# Launching and terminating a helper app with a sandbox main app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a main app with a bundled helper app within. The helper app is a necessity for the main app to function correctly. As of right now, I have the main app launch the helper app on launch, and have the main app send a notification telling the helper app to terminated through the `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` on the termination of the main app.

This way works most of the time. However, if the main app is force closed, the helper app remains running (no notification is sent. I am using the `AppDelegate`'s `applicationWillTerminate` method to send the notification).

Is there a way to make the running of the helper app more reliable? Also, is there a better way to make the communication between the two apps (ie not `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`; is there away to communicate through app bundles?)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use a common approach of '***pinging***' each other to indicate the app is still alive (also via notifications) like once a minute.

No notification received after some timeout being the helper app's trigger to shut itself down.

Not super-elegant but pragmatic and proven.

Or check the list of processes for the other app still being alive, though the latter sounds more brittle to me.

Comment: Thanks for your response!